# Drupal Core Auto Update?

Tags: updating

Is there a way to update Drupal Core without reuploading files and following the UPDATE.php file?  Something similar to how you can update a Wordpress install with a click of a button?  I wasn't sure if there is a module that will allow this?

--edit--

I've attempted the "drush up" command per @Enxebre's suggestion.

I installed Drush to my shared host and it seems to be running correctly. The site is still not updating though. I checked for updates and its still at 7.22 instead of 7.23.

I also had to run an update on Drush.
Here are my results from the terminal command:

Drush self update:

```
drush self-update 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-type: text/html

A newer version of drush, 7.x-5.x-dev (2013-Aug-06), is available.  Would you like to back up your current drush, version 4.3-dev, to /home1/munortap/drush-backups/drush/20130912205746 and replace it with the newer release? (y/n): y
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/drush.inc</b> on line <b>576</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/drush.inc</b> on line <b>576</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/drush.inc</b> on line <b>576</b><br />
```

Drush up:

```
[~/public_html/misadventureinc]# drush up
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' in         <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/drush.inc</b> on line <b>1668</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/drush.inc</b> on line <b>1668</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/drush.inc</b> on line <b>1668</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/drush.inc</b> on line <b>1668</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in     <b>/home1/munortap/public_html/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
```

Comment: Hi, you can upload drupal core and modules through command line with "drush up"

Comment: Thanks @Enxebre. Can you please look at the edit to this post. I installed Drush but I'm still not able to update correctly.

Comment: Did you install drush in a shared hosting environment? It seems that something is not right, `drush up` should not return `X-Powered-By` or `Content-type` those are Apache headers.

Comment: @Steven I followed these steps (minus using PuTTY, everything was done in terminal): http://www.themerforhire.com/installing-drush-hostgator-shared-hosting

Comment: When you run `drush up` you get all that garbage, but nothing else happens?

Comment: You should not be getting any of that, running Drush through command line should not return anything like what is seen above, so it's most likely an issue with the environment it is installed on.

Comment: @Steven correct. It looks like there is a problem with  'fwrite()' in the drush.inc and output.inc files but I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: Well unless you can get Drush working in your environment (I can't help with as I have no idea what it is) the only way is to download the new update, and upload the new files, then run update.php

Comment: I initially up voted the question because I found it good. But now it's turned half into debugging a completely unrelated drush problem, which should be a separate problem. -1.

Answer (score -1):

If you like you can use the CMS Updater module to enable automatic Drupal core updates. Find the module on drupal.org here: https://www.drupal.org/project/cms_updater

If you need more information about the service behind, lokk here: https://cms-updater.com

Excerpt from project page:

> CMS Updater module helps you to keep your Drupal site secure at all times.
>   Right after a new Drupal core release is published, this is recognised by the CMS Updater Service, which in turn will update your Drupal system.
>
> There is no need for intervention on your part – just check your mailbox from time to time, read your PDF update, and see if the automated updates have been successfully completed (or not).
>
> The use of this module requires the **purchase of a CMS Updater licence key for € 29.99 incl. VAT.** This fee covers one year of updates - your subscription will not be automatically extended, although you will be reminded when your subscription is close to expiring. You can buy the licence key directly in your Drupal admin area under /admin/config/system/cms-updater. If you need a hand or more information, visit https://cms-updater.com.

Emphasis on price added for purpose of this answer.

Comment: If you are in any way associated with them, please say it.

Comment: Also, -1 because I don't like paid solutions posted as answers when OP is clearly struggling with totally other, and usually very good solution.